# Is a B&B's cancellation policy enforceable if I never saw it?

Tags: bookings, cancellations, fees-and-charges, disputes

I booked a room at a B&B a month and a half in advance, over the phone. I asked to be sent a confirmation via email and a cancellation policy as I had not seen it at that point.

4 days before the trip we had something come up and wanted to cancel the room.  I realized I had never followed up after booking and I had never received the confirmation OR the cancellation policy.  The establishment is saying its's too late to cancel because they have a 2 week policy. Had I known that I would have cancelled right away as I don't agree with that policy at all.  On top of that, it's a 2 night stay and they will charge for both nights even if I cancel.  Is this even legal?

Comment: Do I understand clearly that you never received and agreed to a written/emailed booking confirmation ? It seems to me you are therefore absolutely free to cancel with no fee.

Comment: Imagine you ran a B&B and were expecting two nights revenue from someone then 4 days before they cancelled. Would you be ok with just not getting revenue for those nights?

Comment: @KateGregory I wouldn't be happy under such circumstances, which is why I'd be sure to present my terms, and ask for confirmation that they'd been read and understood, *before* accepting a booking.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice, but this is fairly basic.  It's legal in the sense that your booking is a contract with the proprietor of the B&B and you agreed to those terms by making the booking.  Not following up is the same as not reading a contract.

You don't list the location but it's possible, *though unlikely*, that cancellation fee is not enforceable because of specific law applicable in the B&B's jurisdiction.  In that case, they could only charge you what is allowed by law.  You would have to look into the applicable laws to pursue that.